# Ruby class instance fields hidden

Tags: ruby

This is a very simple question, but I cannot figure out what is happening here. Here's my simple model:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

end
```

I can write the `first_name` and `last_name` fields for a new `User`, and when I call that user through the variable I assigned it to, I get this:

```
> u
=> #<User>
```

It doesn't show the fields I wrote. But when I do this (for last & first name):

```
> u.first_name
=> "John"
```

Why isn't the full object showing up when I call `u`? Such as `=> #<User first_name: 'John' last_name: 'Smith'>`. What do I have to add to my model to get that output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that is used for converting an object to a `String` is `to_s`, the method that is used for human-readable debugging output is `inspect`. Some environments also use other methods, e.g. `pry` (or some plugin) uses `pretty_inspect` for "pretty" human-readable debugging output. You need to implement those methods.

Example:

```
class User
  def inspect
    "#<#{self.class} first_name: '#{first_name}', last_name: '#{last_name}'>"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What ruby are you using? For me it works:

```
class Testtt
  attr_accessor :a
end

test = Testtt.new
test.a = 1

> test
=> #<Testtt:0x007fdbca785b60 @a=1>
```

Comment: MRI 2.1 I don't know why either. Seems really odd.